# Azure CLI command on powershell is giving '"c:\\\"Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: azure, powershell

[image]

Az CLI is working on windows cmd prompt but they i am trying to execute the same on powershell or ISE it is giving above message and then execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to install

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-2.6.0

as i see Azure CLI is already installed.

Comment: my powershell script is calling Azure CLI . Earlier it was working not sure why is giving this message